# Textview going out of screen in tablelayout

Tags: android

I am new to android and I have used a TableLayout and I am adding two columns of data into it from a string array. But my second column goes out of screen. It seems that all entries of my second column start from where the longest entry in the first column ends. How to make both the columns fit into the screen with like 50% width for both columns?

My code goes like this..

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.findia1);

        TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablay1);

        for (int i = 0; i < s1.length; i += 2) {
            TableRow tr1 = new TableRow(this);
            tr1.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            TextView textview1 = new TextView(this);
            textview1.setText(s1[i]);
            tr1.addView(textview1);

            TextView textview2 = new TextView(this);
            textview2.setText(s1[i+1]);
            tr1.addView(textview2);

            tl.addView(tr1, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


        }
```

xml code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tablay1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
         >

    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess i got the answer.. i used

tl.setColumnShrinkable(0, true);
tl.setColumnShrinkable(1, true);

this does the job!

Answer (score 2):

Give weight `android:layout_weight="1"` for the TextView

Comment: how does this make difference? do you have an explanation?